# PHP search multidimensional array with multiple values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble understanding how to search a multidimensional associative array with more than one value - I've seen multiple examples of how this can be done, but none of them seem to fit my exact scenario.

I have an array like this:

```
$locations = array(

ABC => array("loc1","loc2"),
DEF => array("loc2","loc3")

)
```

Note that 'loc2' is in both nested arrays.

I need to be able to search the array for a value that would match both the key and the value of each nested array using the value of another array that is generated by my application from an API, which looks like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
[callnumber] => Test 8 
[shelvinglocation] => loc1 
[availability] => 1 
[branch] => ABC 
) 
)
```

From this array, if both the branch (ABC) and the shelvinglocation (loc1) are found in the $locations array, then I want to output true.

Here's my code so far:

```
$instLine = "ABC";
$loc = "loc3";

if (array_key_exists($instLine, $locations)) {
  foreach ($locations as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($loc, $value)) {
      echo "match found";
    } else {
      echo "no match";
    }  
}
```

The output of this is "match found", because it's not specifically matching the array key to the list of locations, it's just searching all locations.  The output should be "no match" because loc3 is found in the DEF array, not the ABC array.

How can I rewrite this so that for each given $instLine/$loc combination, the $loc is only looked for in the array that matches the $instline value?

I feel dumb because I'm sure the answer is simple and in the docs and I've just been using the wrong terminology to search for examples. I appreciate any pointers, even a 'here's the documentation you need, dummy'. :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$found=false;

foreach ($locations as $key => $value){
    if($key == $instLine){
        foreach($value as $k=>$v){
            if($v == $loc){
                $found=true;
            }
        }
    }
}

if($found == true){
    echo "match found";
} else {
    echo "no match";
}
```

You should iterate over both arrays and set a boolean value to determine if the value exists or not. Your code is working as expected because you are just checking if the value of $loc exists in one of the arrays in your array (which it does). A conditional check for the matching key is also required

Comment: You can break out of the loops after setting `$found=true;`.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is store the array that matches the $instline value and then search it separately:

```
if (array_key_exists($instLine, $locations)) {
    $arr = $locations[$instLine];
    if (in_array($loc, $arr)) {
        echo "match found";
    } else {
        echo "no match";
   } 
}
```